# Need to VLOOKUP in worksheet in the same workbook based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am a building a workbook (spreadsheet) that has worksheets labeled by month; e.g., "Jan-12", "Dec-12", and so on. I need VLOOKUP to be able to change where it looks based on the name of any given worksheet without having to change the formula every time. I found this answer and it works great for the VLOOKUPs that are in different workbooks which I have also, but I can't get it to work in the same workbook.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[Datafile.xlsx]",B1,"'!$A1:F500")), 3, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

> `CONCATENATE(`*thing<sub>1</sub>*`,` *thing<sub>2</sub>*`,` *thing<sub>3</sub>*`)`

can be abbreviated

> *thing<sub>1</sub>* `&` *thing<sub>2</sub>* `&` *thing<sub>3</sub>*

They mean the same, but the second form (obviously) takes less room, so some people might find it easier to read.

Your question seems to be a little vague –– you didn’t say when you want to reference the same workbook, and when you want access a different one.  So fill in the blank.  And since you seem to have the `VLOOKUP` part working, the question comes down to the referencing part.  In other words, how to adapt

> `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[Datafile.xlsx]", B1, "'!$A1:F500"))`

which we can abbreviate to

> `INDIRECT("'[Datafile.xlsx]" & B1 & "'!$A1:F500")`

So try

> `INDIRECT("'" & IF(`*condition*`, "", "[Datafile.xlsx]") & B1 & "'!$A1:F500")`

where *condition* is the condition under which you want to use the current file.  In words, concatenate a single quote (`'`), conditionally the workbook name (in brackets) ***or not***, then the sheet name (I assume that’s what’s in `B1`), a second quote, an exclamation mark, and the cell range.

Comment: My guess is that the OP only wants to do this in the current workbook now, so is deleting "'[Datafile.xlsx]" from the CONCATENATE and therefore losing the initial single quote ' and ending up with a reference that the INDIRECT can't handle.